# Can NSInputStream be used to read chunks of data with offset to be able to upload large files

Tags: ios, nsinputstream

I’d like to know if there is a way to use `NSInputStream` to read chunk of data with some offset. For example there is a file with size 100MB, I need chunks with size of 10MB but I need the 5th chunk before the 1st chunk.

The goal is to be able to upload large files to a server. The backend expects chunks of data, that can be sent at once. The idea is to use `NSOperationQueue` and to set `maxConcurrentOperationCount` to 5 for example. Each of the tasks will need different chunk to send. I know about `- (NSData *)subdataWithRange:(NSRange)range` - but this will require the whole `NSData` to be in the memory all the time. Which won’t work with large files, so I’d prefer to use `NSInputStream`. Can the chunks be read out of order with `NSInputStream` and how or should another approach be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open file-based `NSInputStream` and then specify required offset using `NSStreamFileCurrentOffsetKey` property. At the same time, in case of implementing upload upon `NSURLRequiest` with `NSInputStream` inside, the size of the chunk is not under your control. Its value hardcoded in CFNetworking framework.